# Regex to get particular set of numbers

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a file path that I am looking to get a set of numbers out of. Here is my string:

```
_uploads/_documents/1254_test_doc.pdf
```

I would like to only get the number set `1254` from that string. I know that you can use the regex for getting digits which would be `\d`.

However, I would also like to account for strings that may look something like this:

```
_uploads/_documents/1254_test_doc1.pdf
```

I am still trying to get better with using regex and this one isn't clicking. Would anyone be able to help me find the correct regex to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pattern `(?<=/)\d+(?!.*/)`, like this:

```
Dim input As String = "_uploads/_documents/1254_test_doc1.pdf"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, "(?<=/)\d+(?!.*/)")
If m.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
End If
```

Here's the meaning of the pattern:

- `(?<=/)` - A lookbehind assertion to ensure that the number must be preceded by a forward slash
- `\d+` - A number containing one or more digits.  This is the part being matched.
- `(?!.*/)` - A negative lookahead assertion to ensure that the number does not have a forward slash that comes anywhere after it.  This assertion allows for numbers to exist in the directory name without causing interference.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
.*\/(\d+)
```

It captures a set of numbers after the last `/`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wL3kG7/1)